# AngularFire ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a problem with angular + firebase.

I have 2 arrays

```js
{
  "lessen" : {
    "-KlL8-2To1zQ6pVdKRe2" : {
      "codelink" : "",
      "demolink" : "",
      "publish" : 1,
      "tag" : "html",
      "tekst" : "",
      "titel" : "HTML - elementen",
      "user" : "8chFY1kE0iS2KjufzAauQ5m1IoS2"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "8chFY1kE0iS2KjufzAauQ5m1IoS2" : {
      "displayName" : "Jur Dekker"
    }
  }
}
```

What i want its a ng-repeat on the lessen, but that he show the displayName from de user.

like this

```html
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="lessen in lessen">
    <td>{{lessen.titel}}</td>
    <td>{{users.displayName (where lessen.user is equal to key from users) }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So actually I want him to take the displayName where user of lessen array is the same as the user in users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get user using its `key`. Also the alias of `ng-repeat` current item should be different than original collection.

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="l in lessen">
    <td>{{l.titel}}</td>
    <td>{{users[l.user].displayName || 'N/A'}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For what is 'N/A' ?

Comment: @jurdekker I just had there to just display `N/A` if no `lessen.user` present in `users` object

Comment: users[lessen.user] and users[l.user]  don't work. (scope[child].child don't work)

Comment: @jurdekker can you provide me a plunker?

Comment: `<td>{{users[l.user].displayName || l.user}}</td>` It wil show the key from `l.user` but i does't show the display name form de users scope with `$scope.users = $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref().child('users'));`

Comment: It takes all the data form the scope with `[$index]` but i want only the `key == l.user`